# Pourquoi les jurons québécois sont-ils des sacres ?

Tags: québec, jurons

Pour autant qu'un non-québécois puisse en juger, la quasi-totalité des jurons québécois sont des [sacres](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/fr/wiki/Sacre_qu%C3%A9b%C3%A9cois). D'après [l'article de Wikipédia](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/fr/wiki/Sacre_qu%C3%A9b%C3%A9cois), cette tradition est essentiellement un exutoire.

> D'aucuns estiment d'ailleurs que les sacres ont constitué, en partie du moins, un exutoire vis-à-vis du contrôle exercé dans toutes les sphères de la société québécoise par l'élite ecclésiastique de l'époque.

Cependant le même contrôle était exercé en France par l'église catholique, et ce genre de jurons n'est pas devenu plus populaire pour autant.

Quelles différences entre le Québec et la France pourraient expliquer cette divergence du français?

Comment: Je voudrais ajouter qu'il y a une microbrassérie excellente, [Siboire](http://www.siboire.ca/#/citations) , dans notre ville qui utilise les sacrés dans toute leur publicité que des jeux de mots.  Par exemple:  «Si boire est un vice, cale verre en est un autre» où «si boire» == ciboire, «cale verre» == calvaire ... etc

Comment: Précisons au passage que les sacres modernes, malgré leur nom, ne sont plus perçus comme religieux. Dans certain cas leur prononciation a été complètement séparée de celle des mots d'origine, et le mot problématique, c'est *tabarnak* pas *tabernak* et encore moins *tabernacle* (qui ne réussira qu'a faire rigoler les gens).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Un juron pour avoir une valeur exutoire doit être transgressif et choquant. Le religieux est une source évidente de possibilités de transgression, les autres étant le sexe et les excréments. L'utilisation de juron religieux est bien présente hors du Québec (j'ai l'impression que tous ceux de mon père était de ce type). L’hypothèse de Raphink me semble donc correcte, la perte de force des jurons a connotation religieuse et donc leur remplacement par d'autres est vraisemblablement liée a la laïcisation de la société française (mais je ne connais pas assez le Québec pour savoir si elle est plus rapide ou plus forte en France que là).

En passant, « juron » a pour moi une connotation religieuse forte.  Le TLFi donne d'ailleurs en premier sens

> Exclamation offensante à l'égard de Dieu.

et ne donne

> Interjection ou exclamation grossière ou familière qui traduit une réaction vive de colère, dépit ou surprise.

que « par extension ».

Comment: Une notation ou une connotation?

Comment: Cela dit, je doute que "tabernacle" ait été utilisé en France. Je pense que cette expression québecoise a probablement été influencée par les anglophones protestants américains, souvent plus éduqués en matière d'Ancien Testament.

Comment: Le tabernacle est pour les catholiques le meuble qui abrite le ciboire et les hosties déjà consacrées, la culture de l'AT n'a vraisemblablement rien à voir... Ce que je veux dire c'est qu'historiquement, même hors du Québec les jurons sont dirigé contre Dieu, responsable du fait qui nous énerve.  Anecdotiquement, ceux que mon père employait étaient tous dans cette catégorie.

Comment: Intéressant, je n'avais jamais entendu un catholique parler de tarbernacle.

Comment: Ma connaissance limitée de l'histoire du Québec contemporain suggère une société particulièrement religieuse, où l'Église catholique jouait un rôle encore prépondérant jusqu'aux années 1970...

Comment: Je soupçonne que Raphink est correcte quand il suggère le rôle possible de l'influence protestante américaine.  L'utilisation du mot "tabernacle" est davantage associé à des sectes évangélique que avec l'église catholique.

Answer (score 8):

Je pense que les sacres ont été fortement utilisés en France par le passé. En témoignent des expressions vieillies telles que "boudiou" ou "sacrebleu".

Il est possible que la plus grande laïcisation de la société française à la suite de la révolution ait un rôle à jouer dans l'abandon progressif de ces jurons.

Comment: Ou _vertudieu_, _tudieu_, ou d'autres mots en -bleu (_parbleu_, _palsembleu_, _ventrebleu_). Sans compter que de nos jours, _nom de Dieu_ reste. Mais le français semble se cantonner à l'utilisation de _Dieu_ alors que les Québecois utilisent d'autres termes religieux.

Comment: Je pensais d'ailleurs que _bleu_ était justement dû à la révolution pendant laquelle les nobles n'étaient pas particulièrement bien vu. J'aurais cru, par exemple, que _palsambleu_ était un raccourci pour _Par le sang bleu!_... mais non.

Answer (score 2):

Les jurons sont des "sacres" des "sacrements"... pendant les guerres de religion les protestants étaient forcés de se marier, communier... bref faire les sacrements à l'église catholique. Le fameux osti et tabarnak font références aux outils de la communion qui étaient particulièrement mal vus des protestants.

http://toutesmeshistoires.wordpress.com/2014/01/21/racinesprotestantes/
Voilà.

Answer (score 1):

Je ne vois pas le rapport entre les guerres de religion et le Canada, mais bien celui entre les jurons, blasphèmes etc. et l'ancrage de la religion (exactement comme le dit cette [réponse](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/423/3177)).

« Palsambleu » est pour « Par le sang-Dieu » (avec génitif archaïque), comme « Sacrebleu », « Parbleu ». Je ne les imagine guère employés de nos jours, même au Canada français, sinon par affectation ou humour. C'est peut-être mieux, non ?

Comment: Merci – mais le bouton share renvoie à trois réseaux sociaux, ce qui n'est peut-être pas un empêchement à citer ; en fait, je ne pouvais alors pas commenter, ce que je puis désormais.