# Jurons religieux usuels en France n'utilisant pas le mot « Dieu »

Tags: jurons, religion

Les québécois utilisent des jurons à thème religieux comme *tabernacle*.

Les français de métropole utilisent-ils actuellement des jurons à thème religieux, à part *Bon Dieu* et autres jurons contenant le mot *Dieu*

Le seul qui me vient à l'esprit est [Jésus Marie Joseph](http://www.skipass.com/forums/sports/ski/sujet-79126-0.html) que j'ai entendu relativement souvent, mais qui est une forme d'auto-dérision.

*([inspiré par Evpok](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/419/pourquoi-les-jurons-quebecois-sont-ils-des-sacres))*

Comment: Il y a bien _Doux Jésus!_ mais j'ai du mal à appeler ça un juron.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Bon sang ! (vient de "par le sang de Dieu", [source](http://www.expressio.fr/expressions/bon-sang-palsambleu.php)). C'est tellement entré dans l'usage courant que ça n'en est presque plus un juron...

Answer (score 9):

Un tour du coté de Marseille devrait offrir une belle sélection de jurons correspondant à tes critères (la mère du Sauveur en prend souvent pour son grade). Les jurons régionaux en général offrent une bonne variété...

Ce [site](http://www.echolalie.org/wiki/index.php?ListedeBlasphemes) (attention: légèrement "NSFW", surtout si vous travaillez dans une église) liste pas mal de jurons blasphématoires, dont un certain nombre ne contiennent pas le mot "dieu":

> Pétard de moine (déformation de bâtard de moine)
>
> Pute vierge (juron marseillais)
>
> Va te faire clouer, bouffon !
>
> Trou du cul de la Vierge !
>
> Jésus de mes couilles !

N.B.: Nombre de jurons évoquant des dames de petite vertue ("pute vierge" etc.) font *a priori* réfèrence à la mère de JC.

Comment: +1 Intéressant, bien que je n'ai jamais entendu un quelconque d'entre eux.

Comment: Va te faire clouer, bouffon?? Err... what? Sérieux?

Comment: Jamais entendu aucun, mais j'aime beaucoup _va te faire clouer_.

Comment: Jamais entendu "va te faire clouer" (ça sonne un peu québécois, à vrai dire, mais c'est une pure supputation de ma part)... Les autres sont plus standards, je crois...

Answer (score 7):

le fameux "jarnicoton !" de Henri 4, ici le nom de dieu à été remplacé par le nom de l'abbé coton (jarnidieu = je renie dieu)
Beaucoup de jurons sont formés en remplaçant dieu par le mot bleu, morbleu, crébleu, sacrebleu

Comment: Ou même "ventrebleu", même si c'est un juron encore plus vieilli !

Comment: +1. Il y a en eftet tous les jurons de la fin de la renaissance ou l'on remplace dieu par bleu: Palsambleu (par le sang de Dieu), morbleu (par la mort de Dieu), ventrebleu (?), corbleu (?), jarnibleu (je renie Dieu). Ce qui faisait dire plaisamment à Jacques Prévert que Dieu aussi avait eu son époque bleue (en référence à Picasso bien sûr).  On n'est plus à un blasphème près maintenant...

Answer (score 6):

La plupart des jurons mentionnant Dieu peuvent être utilisés en remplaçant *"Dieu"* par *"bleu"*, pour ne plus le mentionner justement.

Comment: Ma question était à propos des jurons utilisés actuellement. Il me semblent que ces jurons bleus ne sont presque plus utilisés par personne.

Comment: Sacrebleu, ventrebleu etc. sont un peu vieillots, mais partant de là, presque tous les jurons religieux le sont ;-)

Comment: Je trouve sacrebleu, ventrebleu, palsambleu, et compagnie sympa, et aujourd'hui très innocents. Mais bon, je suis aussi fan de Achille Talon...

Comment: les 'bleu' sont toujours employés, peut-être pas ventrebleu ni palsanbleu, mais certainement crébleu, vainbleu ou même juste bleu