# Are Catholics in Quebec offended by Quebecois swear words?

Tags: vocabulaire, québec, comparaison-de-langues, société, jurons

It's less common for Christians to swear by saying things like "Jesus fucking Christ!" or "Goddamnit!", etc. It's more difficult to swear by saying "Jesus Christ!" when the associations of the words "Jesus Christ" is (for example) a loving God who takes care of you and whose love you want to be influenced by.

In my experience, many Christians are so used to people swearing by saying "Jesus Christ" or "Goddamnit" etc that they don't get offended. At worst, it's off-putting, but not offensive.

I'm curious how it's like for Catholics, with words like "Ostie!" and "Tabernak!". Do Catholics use these swear words? Do non-Catholics tend to reduce swearing in this way in front of their Catholic friends?

Comment: Possibly will be downvoted as more a question about culture than about the language itself. But I think it's interesting enough.

Comment: @LukeSawczak possibly, and thanks for the warning. one argument about why it is legitimate, is that how "strong" certain swear words are, is indeed about the language. "may i tutoyer with my university professors in Quebec, or is that offensive?" questions are allowed on here; so maybe this question should be, by the same argument?

Comment: This question is not related to the French language. The literal French translation "Jésus-Christ" is not a swearing expression in the French language.

Answer (score 7):

Most swear words and taboos in any language come from body parts and functions, family/hierarchy, sex, and religion.  [Steven Pinker](https://www.openculture.com/2012/08/steven_pinker_explains_the_neuroscience_of_swearing.html) gives particular attention to le sacre *tabarnak, câlisse, ostie* being religious swear words in Québec French but not in France.

In [Body or the Soul?: Religion and Culture in a Quebec Parish, 1736-1901](https://books.google.com/books?id=uSrCDAAAQBAJ&lpg=PA168&ots=-o8SXzM04U&dq=steven%20pinker%20on%20quebec%20swear%20words&pg=PA166#v=onepage&q=steven%20pinker%20on%20quebec%20swear%20words&f=false) Frank A. Abbott documents the history of Catholicism in Québec and the influence of the Church on taboos.  The difference between *juron* et *sacre* carries weights and remarks that their sacre vocabulary outran that of France, but it represents to date "only about 20 per cent of the impressive corpus of Québec profanity."  I assume that is skewed by the anglo/bilingual aspect.  It was only after 1849 that ecclesiastical condemnation of blasphemy rose to note that the Church showed concerns about it during a "creative period" of *le sacre nouveau*.

Obviously I can't speak for anyone else raised Catholic or otherwise since a reaction to taboos and swearing is personal, but there is some data I can add.  While I am not easily offended by these words, it's all about context.  I had a hard time not giggling when I first heard the word "tabernacle" **in English during Mass** in the US after living in Montréal. It still makes me code switch and does not invoke anything religious for me now in spite of years of Catholic school.  It just means *tabarnak,* and I would not use it in delicate company.  Context.

The article [Québecois Swear Words that Confuse the French](https://theculturetrip.com/north-america/canada/quebec/articles/13-quebecois-swear-words-that-confuse-the-french/) includes tabarnak, câlice, baptême, sacrament, ostie de colon, et on s'en coliss.  Clearly many French speakers in Québec use these words, and many of them are de facto Catholic.

Comment: Are you saying that in a sermon on Exodus in Quebec, one wouldn't mention the tabernacle?

Comment: @LukeSawczak Of course it comes up, good and timely example :) *Le tabernacle* does not mean *Tabarnak !* in context.  My anecdote was more about my own problems code switching since I rarely hear the word in English (and only then in a sacred context) but frequently enough in French for L1 attrition. Here is a clip from Webtélé de l'Église catholique de Québec where around 1:30 you hear four clear syllables of tabernacle spoken during the Homily. [ecdq.tv/immaculee-conception-2008-homelie-du-cardinal-ouellet/]

Comment: Merci pour le lien. But what's curious for me is why, if you're not liable to laugh at "le tabernacle", the English *does* remind you of the *juron* ? Or do you have the same reaction to "le tabernacle"?

Comment: @LukeSawczak FWIW, Spanish also uses *(h)ostia* as a swear word. I didn't make the connection with its religious origin until I heard about the fr-Ca *Ostie*

Comment: Voilà c'est ça, c'est tellement rare d'en entendre parler hors de contexte des jurons. Puis c'est tellement stigmatisé, c'est la première association sémantique pour moi. C'est un peu comme la réaction de certains élèves FLES (/anglophones) quand je leur dis de se taire et je fais « chut ! » mais là du coup je ne suis pas très vite arrivée à comprendre pourquoi....

Answer (score 4):

Contexte. Bien évidemment au début de la [colonie](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fran%C3%A7ais_qu%C3%A9b%C3%A9cois#Histoire) [on avait](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sacre_qu%C3%A9b%C3%A9cois#Histoire) les [jurons](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/14388/26366) religieux de France, surtout basés sur le mot *dieu*.

> Le français québécois se distingue aussi par les « [sacres](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sacre_qu%C3%A9b%C3%A9cois) », jurons
> tirés du vocabulaire ecclésiastique. On attribue généralement cette
> particularité au fait que le peuple québécois a très longtemps vécu
> sous l'emprise très serrée de l'Église catholique, et ce, depuis la
> colonie (XVII<sup>e</sup> siècle) mais en particulier dans la première moitié du
> XX<sup>e</sup> siècle, jusqu'à la [Révolution tranquille](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/R%C3%A9volution_tranquille) (1960-1970). Le blasphème
> serait une réaction à cette mainmise [de l'Église catholique] qui
> s'exerçait aussi bien sur l'État que sur la vie privée. Le fait que le
> clergé ait encouragé la population à se soumettre aux conquérants en
> [1760](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conqu%C3%AAte_de_1759-1760) et [1837](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/R%C3%A9bellion_des_Patriotes) n'a fait qu'amplifier cette forme de protestation.
>
> [ Wikipédia, le  « [Français québécois](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fran%C3%A7ais_qu%C3%A9b%C3%A9cois#Sacres) », notes omises, lien ajouté ]
>
> L'indignation du Canadien français contre son clergé ne pouvant se
> ventiler directement, elle sera refoulée et s'exprimera de façon
> détournée, biaisée: par le blasphème.
>
> [ *La vraie nature des sacres québécois*, Jean-François Vallée ds. [Le Devoir](https://www.ledevoir.com/opinion/idees/139840/libre-opinion-la-vraie-nature-des-sacres-quebecois), citant Heinz Weinmann (1993) ]

Ces jurons proviennent de catholiques eux-mêmes, et l'importance de la rébellion aurait supplanté celle du blasphème dans un contexte sociétal. En ce qui a trait à la [sécularisation](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/422/26366), on notera que la Révolution tranquille se produit près de deux siècles après la Révolution française... Par ailleurs en 2011, « le christianisme est la religion de la majorité des Québécois, avec 82,2 % de la population » et « 74,7 % des chrétiens québécois sont catholiques » ([Wikipédia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Religion_au_Qu%C3%A9bec)) :

> Les sacres sont encore couramment utilisés, mais bien que la société
> québécoise se soit sécularisée, ils constituent encore des « gros mots
> » qu'on évitera dans un discours standard. En revanche, il en existe
> depuis toujours des dizaines de variantes atténuées qui, elles,
> peuvent être utilisées sans problème. Par exemple, *crisse, câlisse,
> hostie* et *tabarnak* peuvent devenir respectivement *christophe,
> câline, ostination* et *tabarnouche ou tabarouette*, formes tout à
> fait inoffensives, qui peuvent même dans certains cas être perçues
> comme faiblardes.
>
> [ Wikipédia, le « [Français québécois](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fran%C3%A7ais_qu%C3%A9b%C3%A9cois#Sacres) » ]
>
> Les sacres pouvant être considérés blasphématoires ou offensants
> envers la communauté religieuse catholique, ils peuvent être remplacés
> par des euphémismes comme « tabarouette » en lieu et place de «
> tabarnak », lequel est dérivé du mot « tabernacle ». Les sacres sont
> aussi utilisés dans le français acadien, mais plus rarement et avec
> des variantes régionales.
> [...]
>  [...] Toutefois, sacrer s'est répandu dans toutes les
> couches de la population, même chez les classes plus instruites.
>
> [ Wikipédia, « [Sacre québécois](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sacre_qu%C3%A9b%C3%A9cois#Utilisation) » ]

Il serait difficile de se tromper en disant que des catholiques ont employé et emploient ces jurons.

Plus généralement ce sont des termes ecclésiastiques référant surtout à des objets de culte et aux sacrements (rite) et la référence au Christ par le truchement de *crisse* n'est qu'un élément parmi d'autres finalement ; c'est certainement le juron dont l'intensité est la plus grande. Il faut enfin noter que ces interjections font aussi l'objet d'[emplois](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sacre_qu%C3%A9b%C3%A9cois#Utilisation) comme substantifs, adjectifs ou verbes et de compositions diverses, illustrant leur productivité et leur indépendance de la sémantique religieuse.

---

Mon expérience personnelle c'est qu'avec des gens (très) pratiquants (et c'est davantage ce critère-là à mon avis plutôt que l'appartenance à une religion en soi qui modulerait mon emploi) ou plus âgés, ou parfois devant des enfants, j'évite de les employer, incluant probablement les versions atténuées, par politesse ou pour ne pas avoir à en discuter. C'est aussi le cas avec le discours standard formel (entrevue, professionnel etc.). J'en emploie très souvent dans la langue familière, avec des amis, sur le site etc. ou quand je suis en colère, surpris ou que je me cogne. Il y a aussi des emplois « hypocoristiques » ([*petit crisse*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/petit_crisse) ; Wiktionnaire parle d'admiration involontaire ; je pense aussi, différemment, à *petit Jésus* et *mon doux*). Comme avec une ensemble d'autres termes ou locutions, certains emplois sont marqués et relèvent d'un [registre (familier)](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Registre_familier) particulier.